# How to access remote docker from windows gitlab runner

Tags: node.js, gitlab-ci-runner

i am beginner in gitlab ci/cd. I want to build image on remote docker by using windows gitlab runner. How i can connect with remote docker from windows gitlab runner. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

````
this works for me. add environment environment = ["DOCKER_HOST=tcp://example:2375"] and [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "alpine:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
name = "windows gitlab runner"
url = "http://192.168.1.56:909/"
id = 5
token = "token"
token_obtained_at = 2023-01-06T08:09:13Z
token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
executor = "shell"
shell = "powershell"
environment = ["DOCKER_HOST=tcp://example:2375"]
[runners.custom_build_dir]
[runners.cache]
MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
[runners.cache.s3]
[runners.cache.gcs]
[runners.cache.azure]
[runners.docker]
tls_verify = false
image = "alpine:latest"
privileged = false
disable_cache = false
volumes = ["/cache"]

```
````

Comment: Your answer needs some clean up and supporting information. Please edit the answer to correct the code blocks, and add information on _why_ or _how_ this solves the problem.